# Problem starting ngnix server, error 400 how can I solve it?

Tags: docker, nginx, web

I run the command `docker run -p 8080:80 nginx` for port 80 to be used on my machine as 8080, I get the normal response:

```
Unable to find image 'nginx:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/nginx
c1dfc7e1671e: Download complete
85c41ebe6d66: Download complete
8f28d06e2e2e: Download complete
6f837de2f887: Download complete
578acb154839: Download complete
e398db710407: Download complete
7170a263b582: Download complete
Digest: sha256:86e53c4c16a6a276b204b0fd3a8143d86547c967dc8258b3d47c3a21bb68d3c6
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:latest
/docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Enabled listen on IPv6 in /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Sourcing /docker-entrypoint.d/15-local-resolvers.envsh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
/docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2023/11/14 17:38:19 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2023/11/14 17:38:19 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.25.3
2023/11/14 17:38:19 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 12.2.0 (Debian 12.2.0-14)
2023/11/14 17:38:19 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.15.133.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2
2023/11/14 17:38:19 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2023/11/14 17:38:19 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2023/11/14 17:38:19 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 29
2023/11/14 17:38:19 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 30
2023/11/14 17:38:19 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 31
2023/11/14 17:38:19 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 32
2023/11/14 17:38:19 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 33
2023/11/14 17:38:19 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 34
2023/11/14 17:38:19 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 35
2023/11/14 17:38:19 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 36
```

but when I go to the browser and make a request I get the error:

```
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Nov/2023:17:38:58 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x03I" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Nov/2023:17:38:58 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02L\x01\x00\x02H\x03\x03\xFDe\x80?\xD4\xC1\xEC4t\xF6\x8F\xB8\xD8\x9E\xDFu\x9A 2r\xC2d\x01l." 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Nov/2023:17:38:58 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02,\x01\x00\x02(\x03\x03W\xA5\x8C\xD8\x88UJ\x85\xB1\xC1]\x04]P\x1D\xEFV\x88\xC1\x8ALh\xF3\xFBI\xA4+\x8B\x8B)\xA5\xF6 \xBAW\xD9\x12\xE67X\x80\x13\xE6c\xEAa\xA2\x94V\x89\xA6\x06`\x02*/\xC3Hd\x22!\x5CaK|\x00 ZZ\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03\xC0+\xC0/\xC0,\xC00\xCC\xA9\xCC\xA8\xC0\x13\xC0\x14\x00\x9C\x00\x9D\x00/\x005\x01\x00\x01\xBFzz\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x0E\x00\x0C\x02h2\x08http/1.1\x00\x0B\x00\x02\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0E\x00\x0C\x00\x00\x09localhost\x00\x05\x00\x05\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00-\x00\x02\x01\x01\x003\x00+\x00)\xAA\xAA\x00\x01\x00\x00\x1D\x00 \xF4\x22\xE8\xB2\x80J\x17\xCA\x82k\xB7\x9Aj\xF4\x86w\xFCpn6\xAEA\xD1\x02\xA4\xD7\x99n\xE4\xD0/S\x00+\x00\x07\x06zz\x03\x04\x03\x03\xFE" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
```

I tried to upload an nginx server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nginx container is getting error because you are trying to use `https` for the `nginx` server which is listening to `http` host port 8080 (mapped to container port 80). `https` won't work since you haven't configured `ssl` and thus giving this error.

##### To solve this, use `http://` instead of `https://` in the URL, like following:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

Following is the log for `http` (working case):

```
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Nov/2023:19:05:57 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Also, below I have attached full logs when I reproduced the issue on my machine:

```
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Nov/2023:18:56:50 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x07\x12\x01\x00\x07\x0E\x03\x03\x0El\xAAz\xABBz\x90\x84<>\x82\x0Br\x15\xEB\xDD\x80\xC9KC\x93B\xDC\xDF\x00\xB2\xD0\xBA\x06\xBA\xBA J*\xD9\xD9\xC8\xAA9\x89\xA7-\xB5L\xFC\xAC\xC7\xD6\x96\x9D>z\x8Be\xFB\xD9o\xBCeH\xAF\xC7\x1E\xD5\x00 \xFA\xFA\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03\xC0+\xC0/\xC0,\xC00\xCC\xA9\xCC\xA8\xC0\x13\xC0\x14\x00\x9C\x00\x9D\x00/\x005\x01\x00\x06\xA5JJ\x00\x00\x00" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Nov/2023:18:56:50 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x06\xD2\x01\x00\x06\xCE\x03\x03\xA3\x90t\xF9\x07\xA3\x05\xF1\xAC\xA8\x94\xF4\xC6.\xD9\x13\x00\xABME%\xEB\x14W\xBEm\xC8\xFC\x1D\xD83\x81 1,\xC8\x9FIlI\x90\xF2h\x8C=8\xC1Y\xE1\x96P\x9A\x93\x11\xD3\xDF\x84Kp\xEA\x973\xA8\x93\xE1\x00 \xAA\xAA\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03\xC0+\xC0/\xC0,\xC00\xCC\xA9\xCC\xA8\xC0\x13\xC0\x14\x00\x9C\x00\x9D\x00/\x005\x01\x00\x06ejj\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00\x1B\x00\x03\x02\x00\x02\x00\x05\x00\x05\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0E\x00\x0C\x00\x00\x09localhost\x00" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Nov/2023:18:56:50 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x06\xD2\x01\x00\x06\xCE\x03\x03\x11$jD\x17/.\xB8\x97\xD0\x94\x11\xA2\x9AE\x99\xBE\x84u\xBBZ\xA4\xB8\x94A\x96\x13\xD4\xD4H6\x13 \xFAk\xF74\x89O]\xF8s.\xF6\xB3G(\x1A\x1D!Ry\xBFN\xAFR\xA0=\xE1\xA5\x94\x15ife\x00 ::\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03\xC0+\xC0/\xC0,\xC00\xCC\xA9\xCC\xA8\xC0\x13\xC0\x14\x00\x9C\x00\x9D\x00/\x005\x01\x00\x06e\xCA\xCA\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x05\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFE" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
172.17.0.1 - - [14/Nov/2023:18:56:50 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x06\xB2\x01\x00\x06\xAE\x03\x03\x08\xB6\x0C\x80\xFD\x07\xAB\xE9?!\xB9X\xF8H\x9A\xB8rg\x89\xC9\x195\xE0\xAF\xF2\x12\xCC\x96\xFE\xDC\xB8\xF3 c\x9C\xD2\x16\x1D\x8B\xA8\x09\x96>w\x11\xDE\x93\xB5\x93\xA3j\x17\x9B\xB2\x7F\x02\xA0\xD5~\xA5\x5Cx\xD7\x9E\xD6\x00 JJ\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03\xC0+\xC0/\xC0,\xC00\xCC\xA9\xCC\xA8\xC0\x13\xC0\x14\x00\x9C\x00\x9D\x00/\x005\x01\x00\x06E**\x00\x00\x00" 400 157 "-" "-" "-"
```